# How to give sapling tree gen more volume?

Tags: modeling, particles, sapling-addon

I found this foliage artwork on Art Station https://www.artstation.com/artwork/r9dBXL, and I am in the process of trying to replicated it. In his software description, he said he used Blender, and by looking at the branches it looks like he is using *Sapling Tree Gen* add-on.

Here is the reference vs my failed attempt.
[image]
[image]

My problem is the branches looks like kabobs with leaves on it, and the core of my tree is hollow. To fix it I've tried many settings in the add-on. For example, adding more leaves, less leaves, adding more branches, changing the rotation of the branches etc. None of it really helped me achieve the volume I was looking for.

Now you guys are probably going to point me to this guide https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wPBX9kqcHzE, but with this technique I also had trouble achieve the reference look. In my experiments the leaf cluster I made looked like rounded spheres, which looks unnatural.

For example, my tree looked like this artwork I found.
[image]

Does anyone know what this person did to give their sapling tree gen so much volume?

If you look closely at the reference tree it looks natural. It just doesn't look like they used a sphere here and sticked leaf card normals to the surface.

Right now, my hunch is the ref tree was made using particle system to generate location of the leaves from the tree's center with some fall off curve. Or there is a setting in sapling tree gen that lets you add more branches to the center of the tree, thus when you add leaves it will look denser in the center creating the illusion of having more volume.

Honest, at this point I am just lost, so does anyone have any ideas of how to get the same look?

Comment: Somewhere in sapling there is an iteration option which will create smaller and smaller sub-branches.

Comment: Could also be that the leaf object is not a single leaf but a full cluster.